# Transform a string thats contain a json to pure json format

Tags: go

I have a string whats contains JSON. I need to transform that string to a JSON object in order to send it in a PUT request. Here is the string I have:

```
{
  "changed": "Jhon",
  "created": "Marc",
  "date_changed": "2020-10-06T12:51:36Z",
  "date_created": "2020-10-06T12:51:36Z",
  "title": "\u003ch2\u003e\u003c/h2\u003e"
}
```

Edit:

This code works for me; the user represents the JSON string upper in the question.

```
    in := []byte(user)
    var raw map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(in, &raw); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(raw["changed"])
    out, err := json.Marshal(raw)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Edit 2: this works, too, and is easier

```
   strings.NewReader(user)
```

Comment: simple i have a json as a string i needed convert that to a json object

Comment: sorry i mixed concepts from other languages, i think a json object in go is a map that can be access with the key values

Comment: my goal is pass that string into a request body, and my fist thot was put that string into a map.

Comment: A request body takes an `io.Reader` - Zombo shows neatly how to convert a string to an `io.Reader`

Answer (score 2):

OP is asking how to use a `string` containing a JSON document as a request body.

The body argument to [http.NewRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequest) is an [io.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader).  Use the [strings.NewReader](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#NewReader) function to wrap a string with  an io.Reader:

```
req, err := http.NewRequet("PUT", url, strings.NewReader(user))
```